# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: while running nginx in dockerfile

Tags: docker, nginx

I am new to docker. I am trying to run nginx using a dockerfile in an openshift environment. I initially set the user and group permissions, using:

```
RUN groupadd -g 10000 www-data
RUN useradd -g www-data www-data
```

and assign it root privileges using: (OS being CentOS)

```
RUN usermod -aG wheel www-data
USER www-data
```

the user in `nginx.conf` is `www-data` as well.

However when I run `exec nginx`
I am getting an error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/logs/abc.log'
```

Have tried assigning all privileges to `/app` , `/app/logs`; but this did not solve my problem.

Can someone please suggest a solution

Comment: Can you try creating `abc.log` file manually and assigning it write/edit permissions.

Comment: It seems you are facing similar issue to this: https://forums.docker.com/t/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-code-manage-py/3410

Try the solution specified there.

Comment: Is SELinux enabled? Is /app/logs a volume mount? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I have tried to disable SELinux temporarily. Tried adding setenforce 0 to my docker file, but the file failed to build.